# i getting this error: The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "foreign_key1"

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE singer( 
    name varchar(50) primary key,
    email varchar(50) not null,
    account_number varchar(50) not null,
    balance int not null
);
create table song(
    id int primary key,
    name varchar(50) not null,
    singer varchar(50) foreign key references singer,
    producer varchar(50) not null,
    album varchar(50) not null,
    total_sell int not null
);
CREATE TABLE producer(name VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY);
ALTER TABLE song ALTER COLUMN producer VARCHAR(20);
ALTER TABLE song ADD CONSTRAINT foreign_key1 FOREIGN KEY(producer) REFERENCES producer;
```

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: Format... `Constraint foreign_key1 Foreign Key (producer) References Producer (name);` You will most likely get an error on the `Singer` column because you are not referencing a column name on the `Singer` table. Link for your learning experience... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL you can use this:

```
CREATE TABLE producer(
   name varchar(20),
   PRIMARY KEY (name)
);
CREATE TABLE song(
     id int,
     name varchar(50) not null,
     singer varchar(50) not null,
     producer varchar(50) not null,
     album varchar(50) not null,
     total_sell int not null,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     CONSTRAINT `foreign_key1` FOREIGN KEY (`producer`) REFERENCES `producer` (`name`)
);
```

OR:

```
ALTER TABLE `song`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `foreign_key1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`producer`)
      REFERENCES `producer` (`name`)
      ON DELETE NO ACTION
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

you can see [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22512b/1).

I can advise you to declare the same length as the name column. es. varchar(50)